# Django - Add attribute to serializer and order list based on Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

what I'm trying to get a data based on foreign keys.
Let's say I have these models:

```
# models.py
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 64)

class Game(models.Model):
    score = models.IntegerField()
    player = models.ForeignKey('Player', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='player', blank=False, null=False)

class InjuredPlayer(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey('Player', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=False, null=False)
```

I'm using REST framework so I have this serializer. And I want to add an attribute that is the sum of all Game scores to the Player serializer.

```
# Serializer
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Get the sum of Game scores of the player
    # sum_of_scores = ________________
  class Meta:
    model = Player
    # Use sum_of_scores as a field on the serializer
    fields = ('activity', 'logo', 'sum_of_scores')
```

Then, what want to do is display the list of players, with their sum of scores, if they are on InjuredPlayer. So in my class:

```
class PlayerList(APIView)
```

The queryset should be something like:

```
# I tried this
queryset = Player.objects.filter(injuredplayer__player=id)
```

How you do filter the objects that are not on the other table.
And is it possible to order the list based on the sum_of_scores? If so, how?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the sum of all fields in the serializer, use **serializerMethodField**

```
from django.db.models import Sum
# also import Game model
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sum_of_scores = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'sum_of_scores')

    def get_sum_of_scores(self, obj):
        return Game.objects.filter(player=obj).aggregate(Sum('score'))
```

**NOTE**
Your model structure is not optimal, you can remove the **InjuredPlayer** model and and new field to **Player** like **is_injured** .And set it to default false. And also Game models related name should be "games" or something. So that you can easily reverse reference. In your current structure , to get all the games related to a player you should call player.player.all(). If you change it to games, that will be player.games.all()

So the new structure should be

```
# models.py
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 64)
    is_injured = models.BooleanField(dafault=False)

class Game(models.Model):
    score = models.IntegerField()
    player = models.ForeignKey('Player', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='games', blank=False, null=False)
```

And the serializer becomes

```
# Serializer
from django.db.models import Sum
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sum_of_scores = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'is_injured', 'sum_of_scores')

    def get_sum_of_scores(self, obj):
        return obj.games.all().aggregate(Sum('score'))
```